# GTLServiceYouTube executeQuery callback not called

Tags: ios, multithreading, youtube-data-api

GTLServiceYouTube `executeQuery` callback not called  when I execute it in background thread.Video wont get uploaded. It works fine when I execute it in main thread.I get callbacks and video is also uploaded. I can  solve this by forcing `executeQuery` to run in main thread but that affects the UI performance. How can I solve this issue?

My code goes like this ,

```
self.uploadFileTicket = [service executeQuery:query
                                completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                    GTLYouTubeVideo *uploadedVideo,
                                                    NSError *error) {
// code to handle
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution! Here whats happening is, when I run the code in background thread, before the callback comes the thread is detached. Hence we don't get the callback. When I run it in main thread, main Thread remains alive throughout. Hence we do get callback. Hence this problem can be solved by making current thread to wait using following code.

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:stopDate];
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me. Neither does running the function on Main Thread. Any other suggestions? I have tried everything and the completionHandler is not always called.