# Saving AccessToken to Keychain for Google Drive API

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am using the Google-API-Client and the gtm-oauth2 libraries. When the logon successfully completes

```
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
  finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)authResult
             error:(NSError *)error {
```

I am handed back an access token in authResult.authResult

However if I look at what is saved to my keychain either automatically or using

```
[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch saveParamsToKeychainForName:kGoogleKeychainItemName authentication:authResult];
```

I do not see that the access token is saved once I retrieve it. Only the refresh token is saved

If I immediately or any other time do

```
GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth =     
    [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kGoogleKeychainItemName
                                                          clientID:kGoogleClientID
                                                      clientSecret:kGoogleClientSecret error:&error];
```

My access Token is nil

I assume that this is deliberate but I cannot see any documentation on this. Why does this happen and what is the thinking behind it.

Comment: I thought my issue was the keychain. My symptom was the completion handler was never called. The issue was that I was calling GTLQueryDrive from a background thread, this never runs to completion even if service.shouldFetchInBackground = YES;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541282/gtlserviceyoutube-executequery-callback-not-called

Answer (score 0):

There are some variants why data is not saving:

1. Possible the method (*authForGoogleFromKeychainForName* ) is not supported.
2. Possible if a scanner of finger print is existed in the phone, there should be additional feature in settings for using Keychain - we have some problems with the saving on the phone5 where fingerprint is existed.

Comment: My keychain was being saved but only the refreshToken was being retrieved. As it turns out this is all I needed

Answer (score 0):

The reason only the Refresh Token is used from the keychain is that this simplifies the OAuth2 process.

We do not have to verify that the Access token is still valid.

It makes the process easier to program and the cost is negligible.