# GTLServiceDrive executeQuery completionHandler not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, google-client

I'm using Google Drive SDK for iOS and followed the documentation/tutorial given by Google.

My code is

```
[self.serviceDrive executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
    //code
}];
```

The completionHandler is not called most of the times. I tried running this block on Main thread as suggested here - [GTLServiceYouTube executeQuery callback not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541282/gtlserviceyoutube-executequery-callback-not-called), but the behaviour is still the same. Please suggest me a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you verified that `self.serviceDrive` isn't `nil`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is not nil. In fact, I monitored network calls and the google api returns correct data(list of files) too. But the completionHandler is not called.

Comment: Are there error logs that you can share?

Comment: Same issue occured. Any solution?

Comment: I appreciate that this is an old question but did you ever resolve this issue?